# how to replace column value with range in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range, conditional-statements

I have data frame called 'df' and I want to replace values within a range of columns in a data frame with a corresponding value in another column.

1. 6 <= age < 11  then  1

   11 <= age < 16  then  2

   16 <= age < 21  then  3

   21 <= age  then  4

   ```
           age
   86508   12.0
   86509   6.0
   86510   7.0
   86511   8.0
   86512   10.0
   86513   15.0
   86514   15.0
   86515   16.0
   86516   20.0
   86517   23.0
   86518   23.0
   86519   7.0
   86520   18.0
   ```

Results are

```
            age    stage
    86508   12.0    2
    86509   6.0     1    
    86510   7.0     1
    86511   8.0     1
    86512   10.0    1
    86513   15.0    2
    86514   15.0    2
    86515   16.0    2
    86516   20.0    3
    86517   23.0    4
    86518   23.0    4
    86519   7.0     1
    86520   18.0    3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
In [37]: df['stage'] = pd.cut(df.age, bins=[0,11,16,21,300], labels=[1,2,3,4])

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
        age stage
86508  12.0     2
86509   6.0     1
86510   7.0     1
86511   8.0     1
86512  10.0     1
86513  15.0     2
86514  15.0     2
86515  16.0     2
86516  20.0     3
86517  23.0     4
86518  23.0     4
86519   7.0     1
86520  18.0     3
```

or [more generic solution provided by @ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269704/how-to-replace-column-value-with-range-in-pandas-dataframe/44269746#comment75547677_44269746):

```
In [39]: df['stage'] = pd.cut(df.age, bins=[0, 11, 16, 21, np.inf], labels=False, right=True) + 1

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
        age  stage
86508  12.0      2
86509   6.0      1
86510   7.0      1
86511   8.0      1
86512  10.0      1
86513  15.0      2
86514  15.0      2
86515  16.0      2
86516  20.0      3
86517  23.0      4
86518  23.0      4
86519   7.0      1
86520  18.0      3
```

Comment: Nice! Way better than using conditional statements.

Comment: Great answer! I always forget pd.cut for this scenario. Next time:)

Comment: @Thank you guys ! :-)

Comment: `pd.cut(df.age, bins=[0, 11, 16, 21, np.inf], labels=False, right=True) + 1` might be more generic (both for bins and labels).

Answer (score 4):

Using `np.searchsorted`

```
a = np.array([-np.inf, 6, 11, 16, 21, np.inf])
df.assign(stage=a.searchsorted(df.age, side='right') - 1)

        age  stage
86508  12.0      2
86509   6.0      1
86510   7.0      1
86511   8.0      1
86512  10.0      1
86513  15.0      2
86514  15.0      2
86515  16.0      3
86516  20.0      3
86517  23.0      4
86518  23.0      4
86519   7.0      1
86520  18.0      3
```

**Timing**
*small data*

```
%%timeit
a = np.array([-np.inf, 6, 11, 16, 21, np.inf])
df.assign(stage=a.searchsorted(df.age, side='right') - 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 288 µs per loop

%%timeit
df.assign(stage=pd.cut(df.age, bins=[0,11,16,21,300], labels=[1,2,3,4]))
1000 loops, best of 3: 668 µs per loop
```

Comment: Updating my bag of useful function:) +1